How to get an understanding of information entropy.
In my book it says:

If we are told that a highly improbable event has occurred, we will have received more information than if we were told that some likely event has just occurred.

I have come up with an example to try and get a handle on this. Suppose we have a really big book, say 2000 pages. If on every page of that book there are 200 words and all of them are the word "hello". If we randomly select a page on that book and randomly choose a word, we will choose the word "hello". We have learned everything there is to know about that book.
Does this contradict the extract from my book above? We have received all the information there is to know about the book and the chance of choosing the word hello was guaranteed.
Okay, let us choose a page at random and select a word and replace that with "goodbye". The total information contained in this book is ["hello", "goodbye".] Now I can see that my example coalesces with the above extract from my book. We gain no information from selecting "hello" and we gain 50% of the information by selecting a "goodbye", which is very unlikely.
Am I thinking about this correctly?

(I think this should be an answer, though it may not resolve your confusion fully.)
Entropy, as in expected information gain, is a property of the distribution of possible events. If your book only contains the word "hello" on every page, then picking a page to read gives you no new information — you already know that the page you select will have "hello" on it. In fact, the entropy of a distribution with only one possible outcome is $0$.
On the other hand, if every word bar one is "hello", then picking a page with "hello" on it gives you very little information — it is highly likely this will be the result of your experiment. If you pick "goodbye" though, then you have gained lots of information! In fact you now know all there is to know about the distribution of words in the book.
I think it is important (and somewhat counter-intuitive) to note that the exact "information content" of an experiment (or draw from a probability distribution) depends on that distribution. Therefore you can't know it if you don't already know how likely it was.

I see, because $p(x) = 1, -\sum p(x) \ln p(x) = 0$.

yep exactly :))

The core idea is that events with lower probabilities carry more surprise or information because they are less predictable. In other words :
Note that $$\text{information content (in bits) of an event }E=I(E)=-\log_2(P(E))$$ where P(E) is the probability of the event E occuring
For a highly probable event (like selecting "hello" with probability 1), the information content is 0, since: $$I(\text{"hello"})=-\log_2(1)=0$$
On the other hand for a less probable event (like selecting "goodbye" with probability
1/400000):
$$I(\text{"goodbye"})=-\log_2(\frac{1}{400000})\approx 18.6 \text{ bits}$$
$I(\text{"hello"})\lt I(\text{"goodbye"})\implies$ selecting "goodbye" gives you more information because it’s less likely, and the rarity of the event increases the uncertainty (and thus the information content).

You are right. I'll edit my answer to correct this, thank you.
